# Informatica date format

Tags: informatica

I convert string to date format in informatica using expression transformation
TO_DATE(input_field_string,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS '). And I want to round off the MM/DD/YYYY/ HH:MI. how do I do this using expression transformation. For example my data is 10/10/2015 10:05:09. I want to convert this to 10/10/2015 10:00 using expression.

Answer (score 0):

Feed the result of your TO_DATE expression (lets call this v_Date) in a TO_CHAR function i.e. TO_CHAR (v_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' )